# Are proj4 strings case sensitive?

Tags: coordinate-system, proj

Is there any reason that case of characters in Proj4 strings would affect their interpretation? Before parsing a Proj4 string, can I lower case all the characters first?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it's case sensitive. Each `+parameter=value` pair are normally case sensitive.

For example with the *parameter*, there are two separate ellipsoid radius parameters `R_A` and `R_a`, which have different meanings.

And an example where the *value* is case sensitive is on case-sensitive systems (e.g. Linux), where the lowercased `+nadgrids=beta2007.gsb` fails to find `BETA2007.gsb` in `PROJ_LIB`. This value is normally `+nadgrids=BETA2007.gsb` for consistent operation across different operating systems.